Create a type for all keys which have a method?
I have an object of the following structure:
const items = {
    a: { create: () => "hello" },
    b: { create: () => "hello", delete: () => "goodbye" },
    c: { delete: () => "goodbye" },
}

I want to create types for all keys of items which have the different methods. So:
type CreateItems = 'a' | 'b'
type DeleteItems = 'b' | 'c'

How can I generate CreateItems and DeleteItems from the items object instead of hardcoding the types?

Here's an example of how that can be done (playground link):
const items = {
  a: { create: () => "hello" },
  b: { create: () => "hello", delete: () => "goodbye" },
  c: { delete: () => "goodbye" },
};

type HasFunction<T, Name extends string> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends { [key in Name]: Function } ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

type CreateItems = HasFunction<typeof items, "create">; // "a" | "b"
type DeleteItems = HasFunction<typeof items, "delete">; // "c" | "d"


To explain, let's look at it a bit at a time:
type HasFunction<T, Name extends string> = 

This is creating a generic type. That means it's a flexible type which describes the relationships we care about, but with placeholder parameters we can fill in later. This generic has two parameters to control it: a T which is the object we want to look at, and a Name which is the property name we care about.
{
  [key in keyof T]: // ...
}

This part is making a mapped type. items has an a, b, and c, and this object is also going to have those three.
T[key] extends { [key in Name]: Function } ? key : never;

This is a conditional type, which is going to check if the object has the property we're looking for. For example, if Name is create, then the object must look like { create: Function }, or something that extends from that (ie, extra properties are allowed). If it matches, we set the value equal to the key, otherwise we set the value to never.
Combining the steps so far is going to produce a type that looks like this (if Name == "create"):
{
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: never
}

And then there's one last piece:
[keyof T]

That is indexing into the object type we just created, the result of which is to make a union of all its values. That union contains "a", "b", and never, but never is ignored.

Such an awesome answer, thanks Nicholas!

I've done about a dozen edits, so not sure which one you mean :)
